# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(1-cos(1/n))$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried different ways to prove if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}))$ converges or not and I am really stuck on this question.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: $1-\cos(\frac1n)=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^4})\right)\sim\frac{1}{2n^2}$, hence the series is convergent by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)

Comment: You can use comparison test + Taylor expansion of  $\cos (1/n)$ and see immediatly it converges

Comment: Thank for your help. But i still didn't learn the concept your talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a student too so I hope my answer is correct.

$1-\cos(1/n)=\cos(0)-\cos(1/n)=-2\sin(1/2n)\sin(-1/2n)=2\sin^2(1/2n)$
Now as $\sin(1/2n)<1/2n \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \sin^2(1/2n)<1/4n^2$

Hence $ |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(1-\cos(1/n))| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }|(1-\cos(1/n))|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }|2\sin^2(1/2n)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }|(2/4n^2)|< \infty $. Because we all ready know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }1/n^2$ converge

Comment: Thank i ve corrected it